# selenium - what is the store command for a href with a css locator

Tags: css, xpath, selenium

I can do a url store from a link with xpath using:

```
store  //tr[td[contains(.,'6 Day')]][1]/td[8]/a@href  my_var
open   $my_var
```

How can I do this with css?

I was able to use this locator:

```
store  css=tr td:contains('6 Day') + td + td          my_var
```

to select the td in question but trying to add `a@href` or `href` at the end doesn't work.  The next open command fails with $my_var unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  CSS locators can't reference attributes.  There's nothing wrong with XPath locators, just go ahead and use them.